# What is the Message Exchange Patterns?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

Can someone please explain what the [MEP](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#soapmep) is? I can't grasp the concept.

From what I figure, is just a concept for two parties to understand each other (i.e. agree on a type of format that the messages they exchange between them must have).

Is this it, or is there more?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Exchange_Pattern

Comment: @org.life.java: I have already read that

Answer (score 1):

In the context of SOAP, it is used to define the behavior of an operation; whether it takes an input, returns an output, and how exceptions are handled. This is defined in the wsdl. See the pattern attribute of the operation element in the example wsdl snippet below (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)):

```
<interface name="RESTfulInterface">
  <operation name="Get" pattern="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out">
    <input messageLabel="In" element="tns:request"/>
    <output messageLabel="Out" element="tns:response"/>
  </operation>
</interface>
```

In this service, the operation takes an input and returns and output (in-out).

Comment: No, this is the MEP definition of WSDL. It differs from the MEP definition of SOAP. There are two SOAP MEPs standardized (request-response and response), they basically provide the superset of interactions that have to be supported by underlying transports.